# How to get view object of Fullcalendar in Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

My idea is to change the selectable prop based on which full calendar view is displayed(month, week, day). In order to have this information, I have to get a calendar view object which contains property type. I tried everything from their documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/Calendar-view) and I still can't achieve this.

Comment: Are you using the fullCalendar vueJS ready-made component? If you are, then that component is documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/vue and in that documentation it tells you exactly how to access the fullCalendar object and its API - see the section of that page titled "Accessing FullCalendar’s API". If you're not using the component, then you'll need to show us your existing code and explain where the issue is

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I'm using that component. And I looked at API and all its methods and I can't get the info about the view object from the API.

Comment: Why not exactly? You need to show your code so we can see what you tried, and show any error messages etc. It's impossible to guess what might have gone wrong.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your reply! I managed to get the info I needed from the API with a this.$refs.calendar.getApi().view.type call.

Answer (score 2):

From [ratkov_a's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312780/how-to-get-view-object-of-fullcalendar-in-vue-js-app/68497367#comment119034090_67312780):

```
this.$refs.calendar.getApi().view
```

Comment: Please provide further explanation or link to docs if possible